# Practical examples of multiplicative regression model

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, example

Majority of the examples of multiple regression in practice is written as additive model. Can you give me some practical examples of a multiplicative regression model (i.e. a model that can be fitted using LR after log transforming of both sides)?

y = c * x1^a * x2^b

log(y) = log(c) + a * log(x1) + b * log(x2)

I do not mean additive/multiplicative model in time series decomposition context nor multiplication in case of interactions.

Comment: River discharge has been modelled in this way. See also Cobb-Douglas production function in economics.